# Intuit QBMS Error: Unknown error returned by SAX parser

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I'm trying to set up a credit card interface on a website using Intuit's QBMS and I've got the XML request set up per the specifications on the Intuit documentation. I've also got my AppID, Connection Ticket, and Application Login set up. But when I do a test, I'm getting the following error:

Unknown error returned by SAX parser. Exception from other package: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Here is the XML Request:

```
$productionUrl = 'https://merchantaccount.quickbooks.com/j/AppGateway';
$connectionTicket = 'SDK-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
$applicationLogin = 'qbms.site.com';
$appID = "111111111";

$xml = rawurlencode('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?qbmsxml version="4.1"?>
<QBMSXML>
   <SignonMsgsRq>
      <SignonDesktopRq>
         <ClientDateTime>' . date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s') . '</ClientDateTime>
         <ApplicationLogin>' . $applicationLogin . '</ApplicationLogin>
         <ConnectionTicket>' . $connectionTicket . '</ConnectionTicket>
         <Language>English</Language>
         <AppID>' . $appID . '</AppID>
         <AppVer>1.0</AppVer>
      </SignonDesktopRq>
   </SignonMsgsRq>
   <QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
      <CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
         <TransRequestID>' . $_transId . '</TransRequestID>
         <CreditCardNumber>' . $_cc_number . '</CreditCardNumber>
         <ExpirationMonth>' . $_cc_exp_month . '</ExpirationMonth>
         <ExpirationYear>' . $_cc_exp_year . '</ExpirationYear>
         <IsCardPresent>false</IsCardPresent>
         <Amount>' . $_amount . '</Amount>
         <NameOnCard>' . $_cc_name . '</NameOnCard>
         <CreditCardAddress>' . $_cc_address . '</CreditCardAddress>
         <CreditCardPostalCode>' . $_cc_zip . '</CreditCardPostalCode>
         <SalesTaxAmount>' . $_tax . '</SalesTaxAmount>
      </CustomerCreditCardChargeRq>
   </QBMSXMLMsgsRq>
</QBMSXML>');

$header[] = "Content-type: application/x-qbmsxml";  
$header[] = "Content-length: " . strlen($xml);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $productionUrl); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the documentation is still not available, in particular https://developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/Common/newOSR/index.html
This is speculation based on my testing. Check to see that the `<TransRequestID>`
contains a number, with only leading or following alpha characters (if any).
The response contains this xml: `<TxnAuthorizationStamp>`

which is your TransRequestID incremented by 1. I think if it can't figure out how to increment it will fail.

Please update any progress you have.

Comment: I tried every variation for a <TransRequestID> and none of them changed the resulting error.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question but I ran into similar problems and was able to get it working.

When I removed this phrase from the request xml packet:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```

The SAX parser error went away and it works.